# Transition Table Cell Width When Text Is Added

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a table cell with some text in it.

```
<td>Text in here</td>
```

I can't set the width with CSS because I don't know how much data is in other cells in the same column. However, I'd like to animate the width property in CSS when my Javascript inserts new code into the table. In other words, when the cell becomes this:

```
<td>More Text in here</td>
```

I'd like the width to smoothly transition, preferably with CSS. Since I can't set the width manually, this doesn't seem to work

```
td{
    transition: width 0.5s ease;
}
```

Is there an easy workaround to this? Or do I have to resort to Javascript?

Comment: JS is the only option I'm aware of. You can't animate to 'auto' AFAIK.