# Use a smooth transition when table width changes

Tags: html, angularjs, css, ngtable

I have a simple table that holds some data on users. A checkbox also controls the display of some alternate data. So for example a row with header `Monday` and value *4000* might become `Friday` *6000*.

When this change happens sometimes the table width changes. Is there a way to transition smoothly to the new table width, instead of the default instantaneous change?

Comment: Can you not simply enforce a fixed-width table if this is that great of a concern?

Comment: @MikeBrant the table is indeed fixed at 100% width. Its some individual column widths that change though.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript would be your only option. You can't animate on a "auto" width with css. Here is a similar question with the same answer: [Transition Table Cell Width When Text Is Added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653172/transition-table-cell-width-when-text-is-added)